# How can i parse data from list fo dictionaries in django template?

Tags: python, dictionary

this is my template, data is a list of dictionries i wanna reach keys and values of each dictionnaries

```
<ul>
{% for item in data %}
{% for key in item.keys %}
    {% if key == 'Server Name' %}
        <li{% if forloop.last %} class='last'{% endif %}>{{ item[key] }}</li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if key == 'Server Price' %}
        <li{% if forloop.last %} class='last'{% endif %}>{{ item[key] }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `items`:

```
<ul>
{% for item in data %}
{% for key, value in item.items %}
    {% if key == 'Server Name' %}
        <li{% if forloop.last %} class='last'{% endif %}>{{ value }}</li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if key == 'Server Price' %}
        <li{% if forloop.last %} class='last'{% endif %}>{{ value }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

PS: you sure you didn't mean `forloop.parentloop.last`?

PPS: is there no way you can redesign your dicts so the keys don't have spaces in them?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

The template allows you to loop over the dict as you would in any other Python code.
Which is very beneficial!

```
<ul>
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {% if key == 'Server Name' %}
        <li{% if forloop.last %} class='last'{% endif %}>{{ value }}</li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if key == 'Server Price' %}
        <li{% if forloop.last %} class='last'{% endif %}>{{ value }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over key-value pair the same way you would do in a for loop in python code:

```
<ul>
{% for item in data %}
{% for key, value in item.items %}
    {% if key == 'Server Name' %}
        <li{% if forloop.last %} class='last'{% endif %}>{{ value }}</li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if key == 'Server Price' %}
        <li{% if forloop.last %} class='last'{% endif %}>{{ value }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```